# mysql - group by the last record

Tags: mysql

My table has multiple records of `n_no` column, and when I `GROUP BY`, it returns me the first record of the group, how do I get the last record?

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE category = 16 AND status = 1 AND datetime >= "2020-01-06 00:00:00" AND datetime <= "2020-01-06 23:59:59" GROUP BY n_no ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 0,30
```

Thanks.

[Solved by doing]

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE (SELECT MAX(datetime) from mytable GROUP BY n_no) AND category = 16 AND status = 1 AND datetime >= "2020-01-06 00:00:00" AND datetime <= "2020-01-06 23:59:59" GROUP BY n_no ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 0,30
```

Comment: Why do you have a `GROUP_BY` when you have no aggregation functions?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using MySQL 8+, then `ROW_NUMBER()` can work here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY n_no ORDER BY datetime DESC) rn
    FROM mytable
    WHERE category = 16 AND status = 1 AND
          datetime >= '2020-01-06' AND datetime < '2020-01-07'
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: unfortunately, i'm in version 5

Answer (score 0):

The idea of "GROUP BY" is to get categories. not to select a record.

```
SELECT DISTINCT n_no, datetime, category, status, etc 
FROM mytable 
WHERE category = 16 
AND status = 1 
AND datetime BETWEEN "2020-01-06 00:00:00" AND "2020-01-06 23:59:59" 
ORDER BY datetime DESC
LIMIT 1
```

in this way you get all records from each n_no with the last date

Comment: i have to group by a column `n_no` , and return each latest record of different `n_no`

Comment: @hatched I updated my code a bit, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below,

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE pk_col in (SELECT max(pk_col) FROM mytable WHERE category = 16 AND status = 1 AND datetime >= "2020-01-06 00:00:00" AND datetime <= "2020-01-06 23:59:59" GROUP BY n_no ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 0,30)
```

Here, replace **pk_col** with the **primary column name** of your table.

Please find a sample [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b012f9/1).